# Circular link list in C

Tags: c, circular-list

I am trying to traverse a circular singly link list in C but it's displaying all of the elements except last one..where is the bug?
may be while condition in else part of the display function be change?but what should the condition be?
functions of display and create of link list is:

```
struct node
{

    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*last;

void create(int num)
{

        struct node *t,*q;
        t=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data=num;
        //list is empty 
        if(last==NULL){
        last=t;
        t->next=last;
    }
    else
    {
        t->next=last->next;     
        last->next=t;
        last=t;
    }
    return;
}

void display()
{

    struct node *q;
    q=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(last==NULL){
        printf("no items in the list");
        return;

    }
    else{
        q=last->next;
        while(q!=last){
                printf("%d\n",q->data);
            q=q->next;          
        }
    }
    //return;
}
```

Comment: Asking others to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to step through your code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Actually, sometimes it's very productive but only when the code author already tried everything else. He can't learn something if he can't find and correct his own mistakes.

Comment: Please, please try 'normal' debugging first, then post here when you're really stuck.  yes, I know, debugging is a boring, miserable exercise that requires taking careful note of eveything that happens at each stage.  Unfortunately, it's a necessary stage of software development and has to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start printing from `last->next` but the condition in the while breaks when `q==last`. So you are not printing the `last` node.

If `else` part is going to be executed, then you know there's at least one node in the list. So you can change the else part to:

```
q=last->next;
do{
    printf("%d\n",q->data);
    q=q->next;
}while(q!=last->next);
```

Answer (score 1):

`last` is also a valid note in this case, and the way you are breaking out of the loop is fine. You should just add a little code after the while loop to print the `last` node too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the last node of the circular list.

Add

```
printf("%d\n",q->data);
```

after the `else` block in `display()`

Or instead of putting an ugly printf after else block, you can consider using 
**do while construct**  .

And you need not do memory allocation for q in display().
Just

```
struct node *q;
```

must be enough. since you are holding only the pointer to traverse the list.